# can I do this without the slow rowwise() function in R?

Tags: r, rowwise

Shipping carriers (eg FedEx) define the length, width and height of boxes according to their relative lengths.  The 'length' is always the longest side, followed by the 'depth' (they use w for weight so depth instead of width), and the 'height' is always the shortest side.

I'm currently doing this to rearrange the labels.

```
        select(products_id,
               products_weight,
               products_length,
               products_width,
               products_height) %>%
        rename(l = products_length,
               d = products_width,
               h = products_height) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(ln = max(c(l, d, h)),
               dn = median(c(l, d, h)),
               hn = min(c(l, d, h))) %>%
        select(-l,-d,-h) %>%
        rename(
                l = ln,
                d = dn,
                h = hn,
                w = products_weight,
                sku = products_id
        )
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: You need `pmin` and `pmax` for the min and max, however the median is trickier. Could you share a few rows of sample data so we can try out some solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work, but it's obviously untested with no sample data:

```
your_data %>% 
  select(
    sku = products_id,
    w = products_weight,
    pl = products_length,
    pw = products_width,
    ph = products_height
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    l = pmax(pl, pw, ph),
    h = pmin(pl, pw, ph),
    w = pl + pw + ph - l - h
  ) %>% 
  select(-pl, -pw, -ph)
```